# What's the efficient way to group this list objects?

Tags: java

I have a list of objects, the number of objects is random.

I would like to ask the efficient code to group the objects in the way that every group has 4 objects (the last group has less than/equal to 4 objects). I need first to know the number of groups, then for each group, I will loop through the objects.

Comment: You really need to go back to your old questions and accept some of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<E> list = ...;

int groupSize = 4;
int groupCount = (int) Math.ceil(list.size() / (float) groupSize);

for (int i = 0; i < groupCount; i++) {
    // Most List implementations have an effecient subList implementation
    List<E> group = list.subList(
            i * groupSize, // "from" index (inclusive)
            Math.min((i + 1) * groupSize, list.size()), // "to" index (exclusive)
        );

    for (E element : group) {
        // ...
    }
}
```